# DB2 SQL Query issue when using Outer Join

Tags: join, db2, outer-join

I am hoping someone can shed some light to this error I am receiving on a Query script ...

```
SELECT 
... 
FROM
LEFT OUTER JOIN DATESA ON DAILY_DATES.ID = DATESA.ID 
table3, 
table4 
WHERE
...
```

I am getting an error message and stuck; can't figure out the issue on my syntax?!

Comment: It would be easier to diagnose your issue if we knew what the actual error message was, and what platform (Linux / Mainframe / iSeries) you were running...

Answer (score 0):

Why do you put `table3, table4` after the join? You specified the tables already in the join

```
SELECT ... 
FROM daily_dates 
LEFT OUTER JOIN datesa 
ON daily_dates.id = datesa.id 
WHERE ...
```

And you forgot to specify your first table after the select (view my example for the syntax)